# Invalid Identifier in query

Tags: sql

I keep getting an "invalid identifier" on `DepartmentName` when I enter this code:

```
SELECT LastName "Last Name", Gender "Gender"
FROM Employee
WHERE DepartmentName =
(SELECT DepartmentName FROM Department WHERE DepartmentName = 'Radiology');
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure `DepartmentName` exists? Are you in the correct scope? You might need a `[USE]` to be sure?

Comment: Share your table description

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. You question lacks critical information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have double quotes in your column names (Say "DepartmentName") while table creation then you should have column with double quotes in select query also.

If you use `Where DepartmentName` you will get an error ora-00904-invalid-identifier

So to avoid error, you have to use WHERE "DepartmentName"

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that the intention is something like this:

```
SELECT e.LastName as "Last Name", e.Gender as "Gender"
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.DepartmentId = (SELECT d.DepartmentId
                        FROM Department d
                        WHERE d.DepartmentName = 'Radiology'
                       );
```

That is, you want to connect the two tables on some sort of `id`.  If you had `DepartmentName` in `Employee`, you would just write:

```
SELECT e.LastName as "Last Name", e.Gender as "Gender"
FROM Employee e
WHERE e..DepartmentName = 'Radiology';
```

No "join" would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood is that a department's name isn't stored in the employee table, but some "foreign key" to a row in the Department table is. Hence you would join those 2 tables

```
SELECT e.LastName as "Last Name", e.Gender as "Gender"
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Department d ON e.DepartmentId = d.id -- guessed this column name
WHERE d.DepartmentName = 'Radiology'
```

If confronted with a choice of join or IN(), use a join.